# Carousel slider not rotating and nav bullets aren't functioning

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I'm trying to embed a slider to a page layout in SP13. For some reason, it's not rotating, and the nav bullets aren't functioning. Any ideas?

Test page: http://compassairline.com/aboutus/Pages/test-slider.aspx

Comment: wich script are you usign to animate the slider?, i cann't find it.

Comment: It's Bootstrap. I added the CSS to Compass.css.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Moved the following JS calls to the bottom of the masterpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```